# CSS transitions not effecting HTML generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css transform that rotates objects on hover.

```
.rotate { transition: 0.2s; }
.rotate:hover { transform: rotate(20deg); }
```

This works perfectly fine when applied to a hard coded HTML element.

However the page contains a script that generates more HTML and inserts it into a div (div.innerHTML = newHTML).

The css transitions do not work on any elements generated by the script.

Why would this be the case and how can it be corrected?

EDIT:
Here is a simplified example that shows my code, however I'm unable to get the example to work at all, the hard coded rotate and the generated html don't rotate and I have no idea why.

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .rotate {
                transition: 0.2s;
            }

            .rotate:hover {
                transform: rotate(20deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="rotate" href="#">A test text</a>
        <div id="plot"></div>
        <script>

            function makeHTML()
            {
                return '<a class="rotate" href="#">I am a HTML link</a>';
            }

            var plot = document.getElementById('plot');

            var text = makeHTML();

            plot.innerHTML = text;

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a snippet of your code

Comment: Can't reproduce it ~ https://jsfiddle.net/6Lpvaooc/. You sure your JavaScript is adding the correct classes to the new elements?

Comment: What you describe is not technically possible. If they have those classes and the `transition` and `transform` properties are not overridden by rules applied by more specific selectors in your CSS, the ones you specified should apply. The simplest way to figure it out is to inspect the added elements, go to "Computed" (near "Styles") tab and check what's specified in `transition` and `transform` properties for the element. It will also tell you what rule sets them. Without a [mcve] we can't help you more than this.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. It would be an example if it worked. I figured out what your problem is, answering now, with example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` only applies to block-level elements. By default, `<a>` elements have `display:inline`. So you need to apply `display: inline-block;`, for the `transform` to work:

```js
function makeHTML() {
  return '<a class="rotate" href="#">I am a HTML link</a>';
}

var plot = document.getElementById('plot'),
  text = makeHTML();

plot.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.rotate {
  transition: 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="rotate" href="#">A test text</a>
<div id="plot"></div>
```